# What do I do if my laptop doesn't recognize input or output devices?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

There is something wrong with my laptop. It doesn't recognize any output or input devices when I open Sound Settings. It shows that the sound is muted and I can't unmute it. No output/input devices show up when I plug in headphones.

I tried typing

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install gdm ubuntu-desktop
```

and then rebooting my laptop. It did not work.
What should I do?